# Merge Sort the sequence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have no idea how to do this problem. Can someone show me how to do this? The problem is I don't know how to do backward substitution. I can't seem to find resources on it, that pertain to discrete 2.

Use backward substitution to solve the following recurrence equations. Give the big-oh notation for each function.

$$T(n) = 4T(n-1)$$
$$T(1) = 4$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(n) = 4T(n-1)$$

This is called a recursive relation. We can find a non-recursive form of it in the following way. First, construct it's characteristic polynomial. This is done by replacing $T(n)$ with $t^n$ and then dividing by the largest power of $t$ that you can to reduce it to its lowest degree.

$$t^n - 4t^{n-1} = 0$$

$$t - 4 = 0$$

From here, find its roots. This polynomial only has one root $4$.

Next, you construct another polynomial from its roots $r_i$ of the form:

$$T(n) = a_1 r_1 ^ n + \dots + a_k r_k ^ n \quad : \text{where $k$ = number of roots}$$

In this case, we have:

$$T(n) = a_1 4 ^ n$$

Next, we solve for the $a_i$ values. We use the base cases for this.

$$T(1) = a_1 4^1 = 4$$
$$a_1 = 1$$

Once we've done that, we have an equation for $T(n)$.

$$T(n) = 4 ^ n$$

---

Just reread your question and noticed you need to perform a specific technique for this called Backward Substitution.

This is done in the following way. Start with $T(n)$ and expand $T(n-1)$ terms.

$$T(n) = 4T(n-1)$$

Then, notice the pattern.

$$  T(n) = 4^2T(n-2) \\
  T(n) = 4^3T(n-3) \\
  T(n) = 4^4T(n-4) \\
  T(n) = 4^5T(n-5) \\
  \dots \\
  T(n) = 4^{n-1}T(1) \\
  T(n) = 4^{n}
$$

There you have it.

Comment: THank you so much! You explained this better than my professor did.

Comment: @MandyMarie No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer you like the best.

Comment: Which part exactly of the second method is backward substitution? It looks like repeated expansion of a recursion relation to me; is that the same thing?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yeah, from what I remember in my classes. It's about the the direction in which we're expanding. $T(n) \rightarrow T(n-1)$ is backwards. $T(n-1) \rightarrow T(n)$ is forwards. It's been a while, so I could be wrong.

Comment: So does the example above work for all similar type questions? Is it really that easy?

Comment: The recurrence relation trick only works for recurrence relations of the form: $T(n) = a_1 T(n - 1) + a_2 T(n - 1) + \dots + a_k T(n - k)$ where $k = $ number of base cases.

Comment: @MandyMarie But the backward substitution method applies to every type of $T(n)$ that has an easily distinguishable pattern to it, not just ones of the form above. Try the method with something like $T(n) = T(n - 1)T(n - 1)$. The backwards substitution method will work for it, but the recurrence relation method won't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you multiply by $4$ at each step, a solution $T(n)=a4^n$ seems reasonable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? I was thinking it would be T(n)=4T(n-1)+4. I'm still having problems figuing out the run time. Also what would be the big oh notation. It would grow pretty fast right?

Comment: Also I don't get exactly what I am substituting. This is so confusing and it doesn't help that it isn't in our book.